# Nets And Solid Puzzle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Just want to confirm we cannot make E, as the Vertical line cannot be horizontal in any folding.

Comment: Not the way it is adjacent to the all white square, correct.

Comment: So Bram28, E is the correct option?

Comment: Correct! E cannot be made